# FirstResponder missing some functions

Tags: xcode, cocoa, first-responder

For some reason some functions are missing from my FirstResponder.

In my MainMenu I have the Redo Menu Item, which in my other app links to the 'redo' function in the First Responder, however this is missing from my new application?

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

The functions in the FirstResponder depend on the type of application that you are building. Your current application doesn't support undo so the generated type of the FirstResponder doesn't have that method.

Comment: I'm building a standard Cocoa application, just like my last app, why are they different?

Comment: Confirm that the type of the FirstResponders are identical.  Click on them in Xcode; browse for the type.

Comment: They're not identical, how can I fix this? thanks for your help